# RecyclerView Didnt show data from json Array

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have Create Recyclerview than i want to retrive data from database to aandroid recyclerview.i retrived data from mysqlserver into JSON formate through php.but data is not show at recyclerview when i try to retrive it at recyclerview.

ActivityMain.java:(Its code is given below):

```
package com.example.chatapp;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    List<PoliceStations> policeStations;


    private static  final String Police_station_URL="url of my php scrip";
    Adapter adapter;


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            policeStations=new ArrayList<>();

         Load_Police_Stations();

    }

    private void Load_Police_Stations()
    {
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Police_station_URL, new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                     int id=jsonObject.getInt("id");
                     String policeStation=jsonObject.getString("Police_Station");
                     PoliceStations policeStations1=new PoliceStations(id,policeStation);
                     policeStations.add(policeStations1);
                    }
                    adapter=new Adapter(MainActivity.this,policeStations);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);



    }
}




    enter code here
```

PoliceStations.java(this activity is used to set values)
    package com.example.chatapp;

```
public class PoliceStations
{
    private  int id;
     private String policestations;

    public PoliceStations(int id, String policestations)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.policestations = policestations;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPolicestations()
    {
        return policestations;
    }
}

    enter code here
```

(Adapter.java)
this activity is used to adopted values takes from datasoure(here in my case it is JSON array file):

```
package com.example.chatapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private Context context;
    List<PoliceStations> stations;


    public Adapter(Context context, List<PoliceStations> stations)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.stations = stations;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_police_stations,viewGroup,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)
    {
        PoliceStations policeStations=stations.get(i);
        viewHolder.police.setText(policeStations.getPolicestations());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return stations.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView police;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            police=itemView.findViewById(R.id.police);
        }
    }
}










enter code here
card.xml:
this is layout activity of my project that is used to design layout for individual item in recyclerview.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">



    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/police"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



</RelativeLayout>











enter code here
```

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Did you check Android Logcat for any errors ? Your recyclerview code is looks right but I suspect there could be error on `StringRequest`'s `onResponse`'s `catch` block

Comment: The code looks good and I dont see any errors, but I suspect that your data is not being parsed correctly and stored into your array , put a breakpoint and check if you are getting the data that you want.

Comment: Data has been parsed successfull .i have tested php script that is displaying output.but did"nt get what the problem is actually.i have tried all method using Asynctask also .but didnt show data.i am very fedup.its part of my project

Comment: In this part of your code: try{...}
catch (JSONException e)
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

Check the error output inside the catch with the log , I'm sure the error is caused when parsing your string to json.

And my recommendation is: use JSONArrayRequest instead of StringRequest, since you are converting String to JSONArray